# How to use Environment variable NEO4J_PASSWORD in cypher-shell

Tags: neo4j, cypher-shell

Can anyone please help me on how  to execute the cypher-shell command by passing username and pwd as environment variables.

I have tried to define these variables in the Environment variables section of Advanced tab in my local desktop. However it is unable to read them and throwing an error as below :

Script is placed in the bin folder of db and executing it from the same location

```
cypher-shell -d neo4j -f test.cypher
```

"The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure"

still the same issue here too:

```
cypher-shell -d neo4j -u  $NEO4J_USER_ID -p $NEO4J_PASSWORD  -f test.cypher
```

Comment: Can you show us how you defined your environment variables?

Comment: I think you need to define `NEO4J_USERNAME` and `NEO4J_PASSWORD` rather than `NEO4J_USER_ID`

Comment: Learn how to debug your code; On the same session; type this: "echo psw=$NEO4J_PASSWORD user=$NEO4J_USER_ID" then press enter. It will display what userid and password it is using.

Answer (score 0):

You first to set both environment variables via EXPORT NEO4J_USERNAME="neo4j" and the same for password

You can also use the `source` command, like `source credentials.env` when the file contains the credentials, which then will be set as your environment variables.

As other posters said you can check the value of your env variables with `echo $NEO4J_USERNAME` or by `set | grep NEO4J_`